# Implementing reCaptcha into a Rails 2.3.12 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, recaptcha

I need to implement reCaptcha into a Rails app form for my internship.  Unfortunately I am still taking my Web Programming classes and haven't gotten into any server side lessons yet, so I am still a complete noob when it comes to submitting forms and sending requests to servers, let alone not using RoR before I started the internship.  I have been trying to find a tutorial to follow, but all that I've found assume more experience with web development.

I have the public/private keys from the site and have installed the plugin, but am completely lost now.  Obviously I don't want someone to just tell me what I should code, but if someone could tell me where I need to go after this that would be fantastic.  I know that I need to add `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` where I want reCaptcha to appear, but I haven't been able to find anything pertaining to what I need to code for the helpers or what kind of JavaScript I need to implement.  I know I need to do some AJAX calls, but again, NO idea what to do or where to start.

Any tips, pointers or references to tutorials would be fantastical and I would love you forever and a day.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh... Wow... FML... Should have been using just `recaptcha_tags` instead of `<%= recaptcha_tags %>`....

Answer (score 0):

look here
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization

http://hwork.org/2009/03/08/recaptcha-on-rails/
http://blog.ncodedevlabs.com/2010/01/26/implementing-recaptcha-in-your-rails-app/

or the best place :
http://google.com